# Can't access the website via Postman but on chrome without any issue

Tags: postman

**Problem 1:** (resolved - Thanks @Ranjith Thangaraju)

I tried to access this website via postman, but I can't do this because I got an error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dmfj8.png

Then when I try to access it on chrome - there's no restriction at all - I can access it: https://finance.vietstock.vn/

Could someone please help me to explain or help with this?

I'm sorry if someone else had the same issue and it is fixed, if you see some other similar, please point me the direction on that

**Problem 2:**

When I access this page [https://finance.vietstock.vn/CEO/phan-tich-ky-thuat.htm],
there is one of the APIs that I've tried to call from the postman but I couldn't, could you please point me a solution for this?

Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTfsM.png

Postman: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P2Qe.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Headers -> Click on **Bulk Edit**
[image: For Reference]

**Add the Following Lines**

> Host: finance.vietstock.vn

> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.99 Safari/537.36

[image: For Reference]

Then Hit Send!! ;)

Comment: your answer makes it very easy and simple :)

Comment: Welcome! Try looking into network tab of chrome dev tools and see through the request headers and check why are they used! you will get to know better.

Comment: I've added a 2nd problem after the 1st one is resolved, could you please help me to take a look at it?

Comment: @howiekarenlam you should add the payload [formdata] in the postman.

Comment: Hi @ranjith, I tried by in postman -> body -> form data -> add 
`code:CEO
s:0
t:`

but I still see the response: Status 302 Found. Is there anything else that I'm missing?

Comment: hahahaha, I got this - I needed to add it as x-www-form-urlencoded. Thanks @ranjith for your all support :)